# oracle sql to group specific column based on some other column

Tags: sql, group-by, oracle11g, sequence

```
SOURCE_TABLE 
------------
OID EVENT_ID  
1   1111  
2   2222
3   1111  
4   1111  
5   1111  
6   2222  
7   2222  
8   2222
```

```
FINAL_TABLE  
------------
SNO EVENT_ID    OID LINE_NUMBER  
1   1111        1   1  
2   1111        1   2  
3   1111        3   3   
4   1111        3   4  
5   1111        4   5  
6   1111        4   6  
7   1111        5   7  
8   1111        5   8  
9   2222        2   1  
10  2222        2   2  
11  2222        6   3  
12  2222        6   4  
13  2222        7   5  
14  2222        7   6  
15  2222        8   7  
16  2222        8   8
```

I am using Oracle 11g. I want to insert data from SOURCE table to the FINAL table. In the FINAL table Line Number need be unique for each EVENT_ID (eg. 1111).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose SNO is a auto increment PK in the Final_Table. Use [ROW_NUMBER() function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm):

```
insert into FINAL_TABLE   (EVENT_ID,  OID,  LINE_NUMBER)
  (
    select EVENT_ID,OID,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY EVENT_ID ORDER BY OID) as LINE_NUMBER
    from source_table
  );
```

Comment: Thanks @Valex. It is working fine if I am selecting from only one table. But actually I am trying to fetch data from 4 tables. Another table also having EVENT_ID and OID present only in source_table. If I rewrite the query as below it is not working.  

`select s.EVENT_ID, s.OID,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY "s.EVENT_ID" ORDER BY "s.OID") as LINE_NUMBER
    from source_table s`

Please help me.

Comment: Just eliminate `"` symbols from  `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY s.EVENT_ID ORDER BY s.OID)`

Answer (score 0):

if i understand correctly you are after this

```
   SELECT EVENT_ID, OID  ROW_NUMBER()
   OVER (PARTITION BY EVENT_ID,OID ORDER BY OID) AS LINE_NUMBER
   FROM SOURCE_TABLE;
```

Comment: Thanks  @ClearLogic. It is working fine if I am selecting from only one table. But actually I am trying to fetch data from 4 tables. Another table also having EVENT_ID and OID present only in source_table. If I rewrite the query as below it is not working.    `select s.EVENT_ID, s.OID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY "s.EVENT_ID" ORDER BY "s.OID") as LINE_NUMBER from source_table s` Please help me.